# Two different results for the same differential equation while using "AccuracyGoal", "WorkingPrecision" and "PrecisionGoal"

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, parametric-functions, precision-and-accuracy

I saw some strange behavior as I was solving a differential equation, so I decided to plot the solution in three different conditions.

First, I defined the initial conditions and some constants:

```
fot = 6.580813053912583`*^-19;
zp = 1000;
lu = 8.418054414588785`*^-33;
```

Then I defined the three differential equations:

```
pr1 = ParametricNDSolve[{(1 + x)^5 D[ (r[x])/(1 + x)^4, x] == l0 (r[x] + (1 + x)^3)^(1/2), r[zp] == fot}, r, {x, 0, 10^8}, {l0}, AccuracyGoal -> 75];
pr2 = ParametricNDSolve[{(1 + x)^5 D[ (r[x])/(1 + x)^4, x] == l0 (r[x] + (1 + x)^3)^(1/2), r[zp] == fot}, r, {x, 0, 10^8}, {l0}, WorkingPrecision -> 75];
pr3 = ParametricNDSolve[{(1 + x)^5 D[ (r[x])/(1 + x)^4, x] == l0 (r[x] + (1 + x)^3)^(1/2), r[zp] == fot}, r, {x, 0, 10^8}, {l0}, PrecisionGoal -> 75];
```

Next I plot the solutions:

```
plotpr1 = Plot[Evaluate[r[1*10^-22][x] /. pr1], {x, 0, 1}]
plotpr2 = Plot[Evaluate[r[1*10^-22][x] /. pr2], {x, 0, 1}]
plotpr3 = Plot[Evaluate[r[1*10^-22][x] /. pr3], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: the three resulting plots]

They give two different plots: in this case  `AccuracyGoal` and  `WorkingPrecision` give the same answer. However in my previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224091/two-different-solutions-for-the-same-contourplot-while-using-accuracygoal-and-wo), I showed that they give different answers (although it was not exactly the same problem).

**Question**
When should I use each one of these options?

Comment: You may want to read this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871

Comment: I read that post before. I find the solution of my problem with the help of another question that I made [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224091/two-different-solutions-for-the-same-contourplot-while-using-accuracygoal-and-wo] . In easy terms, the equation is "stiff".

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation of `PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html): "In most cases, you must set `WorkingPrecision` to be at least as large as `PrecisionGoal`". You didn't, so you obtained iffy results, as simple as that.

Note also that, when you request a high working precision, your input should also match or exceed that precision; that's why you get those warnings when you come to evaluating your second `ParametricNDSolve` upon plotting it:

> ParametricNDSolve::precw: The precision of the differential equation (...) is less than WorkingPrecision (75.`).

That's because `fot` and `lu` are defined at machine precision. You can fix that by defining them to have higher precision. Here I chose a precision of 80 digits to meet and exceed any extra precision requirements that may be encountered during evaluation at `WorkingPrecision -> 75`:

```
fot = 6.580813053912583`80*^-19;
lu = 8.418054414588785`80*^-33;
```

That fixes the second plot.

For the third one using `PrecisionGoal`, let's follow the instructions in the docs and set an appropriate `WorkingPrecision` as well, to a value much higher than the requested `PrecisionGoal`. I often use the rule of thumb of setting the working precision to at least twice the precision goal to be on the safe side. This comes from the fact that the default setting (`PrecisionGoal -> Automatic`) "normally yields a precision goal equal to half the setting for `WorkingPrecision`", again from the Details section of the docs of `PrecisionGoal`. So that's what I'll do here:

```
pr3new = ParametricNDSolve[
            {(1 + x)^5 D[(r[x])/(1 + x)^4, x] == l0 (r[x] + (1 + x)^3)^(1/2), 
             r[zp] == fot}, r, {x, 0, 10^8}, {l0},
            PrecisionGoal -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 60
         ]

plotpr3 = Plot[Evaluate[r[1*10^-22][x] /. pr3new], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

---

I do not feel sufficiently qualified to thoroughly address your final question, i.e. when you should use each of these options, so I will limit myself to telling you that, in my practice, I use `WorkingPrecision` much more often than `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`.

Comment: Let me help: `AccuracyGoal -> a` roughly means that error estimates less than `10^-a` are acceptable.  When the solution is on the order of `10^{-23}`, then you need an `AccuracyGoal` much greater than `23`. For instance for `AccuracyGoal -> 23` would mean a relative error of around 100% would be acceptable, which it should not be.  The first two solutions have accuracy goals of 75, 37.5, resp., each of which is sufficiently large to ensure an accurate solution.  The third solution has an accuracy goal of around `8`, which is too small.

Comment: Also: `precw` is just a warning. In fact, the system raises the precision for you automatically.  The warning is just pointing out an inconsistency in the input, in case it's a user mistake.

Comment: Thank you, your solutions is what I was looking for. Just for curiosity you saw the other [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224091/two-different-solutions-for-the-same-contourplot-while-using-accuracygoal-and-wo)?

Comment: Thank you @Michael_E2, your second comment is really useful.

Comment: I have a reason to suspect that this is not the right answer, maybe I'm doing a mistake again, sorry if I'm wrong. Make this ```plotpr1 = Plot[Evaluate[r[0][x] /. pr1], {x, 0, 1}]```  and this ```plotpr3 = Plot[Evaluate[r[0][x] /. pr3new], {x, 0, 1}]```, once again they don't give the same answer, actually the right answer is the first one, you can prove it solving the diferential equation analitically for the case $l0=0$

Comment: The solution of the differential equation with $l0=0$ is ```psolution[x_]:=6.55456*10^-31*(1+x)^4```

Comment: @MarcoB can you look at my last comment please?